# jquery implementation of Please Wait dialog - safari specific issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

My goal is to display a non-modal jquery-ui dialog box that will display a please wait message along with a loading animation.  This dialog box would display on the page the user is coming from, not proceeding too.  I largely have this working already with the code below.  However, Safari will not display the the please wait dialog.  Firefox and Chrome display dialog and following href.  Safari just follows the href, but won't display the dialog.

If I try a preventDefault(); or a return false; in the click event handler, then safari (and all browsers) will display the please wait dialog, but of course it will not follow the href.  So I do want the default behavior of going to the clicked href, just while going to the href, I want the dialog to display.

I have even tried to do a click handler and inside do a preventDefault(), then open the dialog and then set window.location or location.href, but still Safari will just follow the href and not display the dialog.

Does anyone have any other ideas?

javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        // Register the pleaseWaitDialog element as a jquery-ui dialog widget with certain options set 
        $("#pleaseWaitDialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            buttons: {},
            open: function(event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-title, .ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); }, // hide the dialog title bar 
            resizable: false,
            show: {effect: 'fade', duration: 500},
            height: 120,
            width: 300
        });

        // When a link to add a meeting is clicked, then display the please wait dialog 
        $("a.addMeetingLink").click(function(e) {
            // But wait 5 seceonds before displaying the please wait dialog 
            setTimeout(function () {
                $("#pleaseWaitDialog").dialog("open");
            }, 5000);
        });

    });
```

HTML:

```
<a href="/ripplemobile/trip/addmeeting/81/1/305/308" class="addMeetingLink">Add Meeting</a>

<div id="pleaseWaitDialog">
    <div>
        <p>Please wait</p>
        <img src="/ripplemobile/images/ajax-loader.gif" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick point, edit this function:

```
// When a link to add a meeting is clicked, then display the please wait dialog 
        $("a.addMeetingLink").click(function(e) {

            // ADD

            e.preventDefault();

            // But wait 5 seceonds before displaying the please wait dialog 
            setTimeout(function () {
                $("#pleaseWaitDialog").dialog("open");
            }, 5000);
        });
```

This should solve your current issue.

Comment: I have tried this.  This will make the please wait dialog display (even in Safari) but it will no longer proceed to the href location of the anchor tags.  So how do I both follow the anchor tag and display the dialog?

Comment: You mean display the dialog then follow the href after a delay?

When following the href the dialog will close as you move to the href destination

If you wish to display the dialog then continue to the destination you could add another timeout called after the dialog is opened to go to the desitination

Comment: No do not follow the href after the delay.  I want the href followed and there is an inherent delay because it takes the server time to process the request and serve the response.  During this wait for the server to respond, I want the browser to wait 5 seconds, and if the server has still not responded, then display the please wait dialog.  The dialog would then display until the server finally responds in which case the dialog is gone and the new page displays.  If the server happens to respond before 5 seconds, then the user would never even see the please wait dialog.

Comment: My original code meets these requirements and works as intended in Firefox and Chrome.  Safari does not work.  In Safari, the href is followed but no dialog will ever display.  In fact I can remove the setTimeout function altogether to try to just display the please wait dialog upon the link being clicked and it will still not show the dialog.  It will just wait for the server to respond and eventually go to the href url.  Safari's unexpected behavior is the crux of my issue.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I have the exact same problem.

Comment: @Phliplip - No I never did get a satisfactory answer to this.  Safari just had to be sacrificed and did not have a loading window.